# Make Swashbuckle describe a reference type property as nullable, or make NSwag decorate the client side as Default rather than DisallowNull

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, swashbuckle, nswag

I've a DTO that looks like this:

```
public class OrderDto{
  public CustomerDto Customer{get;set;}
  public ProductDto[] Products{get;set;}
}
```

When Swashbuckle describes it in an OpenAPI 3 spec, neither property appears in the `required` list, and the Customer property is not marked with any `nullable` but the Products property *is* marked as `nullable: true`.

```
"OrderDto": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "customer": {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CustomerDto"
      },
      "products": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ProductDto"
        },
        "nullable": true
      }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
  },
```

On the client side I'm getting deser errors if I don't set the Customer to something on the server side:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Required property 'customer' expects a non-null value

The JSON from the server (ser'd by System.Text.Json by the way, not Newtonsoft) looks like:

```
{"customer":null,"products":[]}
```

NSwag has decorated the client side class with `[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("customer", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]` with the full stub class looking like this:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.5.2.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v11.0.0.0)")]
public partial class OrderDto
{    
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("customer", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public CustomerDto Customer { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("products", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<ProductDto> Products { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm now trying to find out what I need to change and where to get a more permissive behavior:

Ultimately I'd like to be able to not set Customer to anything on the server side, send it to the client and regardless of whether it ser's as `null` or is missing from the JSON entirely:

```
{
  customer: null,
  products: [ ... ]
}

{
  products: [ ... ]
}
```

and I'd like the client side (also a C# app) to deser this and give me an object where the Customer property is `null` (`default`)

Which tool is behaving correctly per the desired behavior?

Should I be changing how Swashbuckle generates the OA3 spec (and how is it done?), or should I be changing how NSwag interprets the generated spec?

Comment: Currently investigating `UseAllOfToExtendReferenceSchemas()`

Answer (score 3):

I applied this in the startup config:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    ...
    c.UseAllOfToExtendReferenceSchemas();
```

it seems a bit of a blunt instrument, but it makes everything nullable, which changes NSwag's `Required` generation from to `DisallowNull` to `Default` for reference types

Comment: It is a blunt instrument, but thanks for sharing

Comment: I think is a good work around, it helped me! thanks